# Azure Devops Web extension User preference/settings storage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

In my ADO web extension, I want to store user settings/preferences. I came across [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/data-storage?view=azure-devops) document to store user-related data using VSS SDK.

I have a few questions related to the storage -

Where exactly is this data stored?

Is storing data this way secure? How easy is it for an attacker to compromise this data?

Answer (score 0):

These data are stored in the Azure DevOps Service, Microsoft will protect this data, this stored data is secure, we don't need to worry about this, If attacker wants to compromise the stored data., they need related permissions to access these date, such as PAT token.

Comment: Is Azure DevOps Service safe for secrets storage? Are there any alternatives for storing secrets?

Comment: It is safe for secrets storage, Sorry but I didn't find the relevant documentation to store the data in another way.